# H2o Python shutdown other cluster as well

Tags: h2o

I have 2 instances running for H2O Python on Port 54321 as well as 54322. So, when, script which is using cluster on port 54321 completes execution, it closes the session. But, it also turn off cluster on Port 54322. Not sure, why it is happening. Is it expected behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you start an h2o-3 instance on port N, it implicitly uses port N + 1 as well for internal communication.

So to say you started an h2o-3 on port 54321 and another one on port 54322 is actually impossible.

The second instance either failed to start (if you used the -port flag for the java process) or discovered a different port (if you used the -baseport flag for the java process).

Shutting down the instance on port 54321 will also free port 54322.